# Windows Vista, Win7 ASLR in Kernel land

Tags: windows, security, exploit

Is ASLR also implemented for kernel land address space addresses? if yes, since which version of microsoft windows exactly?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization) for Windows was first implemented in Windows Vista beta 2 (see [Michael Howard's MSDN blog archive](http://blogs.msdn.com/michael_howard/archive/2006/05/26/608315.aspx) for a brief look at the initial implementation).  All subsequent workstation and server releases have included the feature (including Vista, Server 2008, Server 2008 R2, and Windows 7).

Note that ASLR is only implemented for system files specifically linked to enable ASLR by default.  However, there is a registry configuration option to enable ASLR for all files.  For more information about all of the memory protection and security and features of current versions of Windows, see the detailed article *[Bypassing Browser Memory Protections](http://taossa.com.nyud.net:8080/archive/bh08sotirovdowd.pdf)*.